# Applying conditional to grouped data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby

I've asked a similar question before for R, but I'm now trying to replicate the same task in python. The solution I got in this post is similar to the one I'm looking for.

[Using sapply on column with missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54991972/using-sapply-on-column-with-missing-values)

Basically I need to create a new column conditionally based on grouped data.

Here's some sample data:

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame(data={"Group":[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],"time": 
[0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5],"index": 
[1,1.1,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.67,1,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.93,1.95]})
```

I now want to create a new column,"new_index", that will be equal to index before time 3, but will grow at a different rate starting from time 3, say by 10%. So now the data will look like

```
test2 = pd.DataFrame(data={"Group":[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],"time": 
[0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5],"index": 
[1,1.1,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.67,1,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.93,1.95],"new_index": 
[1,1.1,1.4,1.54,1.694,1.8634,1,1.4,1.5,1.65,1.815,1.9965]})
```

I tried some code like this but it doesn't work

```
def gr_adj(df):
    if df["time"] <= 2:
        return df["index"]
    else:
        return np.cumprod(df["new_index"])

test["new_index] = test.groupby("Group",group_keys=False).apply(gr_adj)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are the values in the time column circular and always ordered?

Comment: @SMir Yes there's an equal number of time rows for each Group and they are ordered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `cumprod` , 1st mask all index with time more than 3 as 1.1 , then we slice the output by not include the one we do not need update, then we `groupby` get the `cumprod` , then assign it back

```
s=test['index'].where(test['time']<3,1.1).loc[test['time']>=2].groupby(test['Group']).cumprod()
test.loc[test['time']>=2,'index']=s
test
Out[290]: 
    Group  time   index
0       1     0  1.0000
1       1     1  1.1000
2       1     2  1.4000
3       1     3  1.5400
4       1     4  1.6940
5       1     5  1.8634
6       2     0  1.0000
7       2     1  1.4000
8       2     2  1.5000
9       2     3  1.6500
10      2     4  1.8150
11      2     5  1.9965
```

Comment: I recently had to use this snippet of code again, so thank you so much! A  more general knowledge question I have is, how are you able to take a Series and filter it/groupby it using other Series? Do Series store information about other Series in the same DataFrame?

Comment: @Elision since the index will match first before the groupby ~

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer that actually increases your index by 10% if the time is > 3:

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame(data={"Group":[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],"time": [0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5],"index": [1,1.1,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.67,1,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.93,1.95]})

def gr_adj(row):
    if row["time"] <= 2:
        return row["index"]
    else:
        return row["index"] + (row["index"] * 0.1)

test["new_index"] = test.apply(gr_adj, axis=1)
```

outputs:

```
    Group  time  index  new_index
0       1     0   1.00      1.000
1       1     1   1.10      1.100
2       1     2   1.40      1.400
3       1     3   1.50      1.650
4       1     4   1.60      1.760
5       1     5   1.67      1.837
6       2     0   1.00      1.000
7       2     1   1.40      1.400
8       2     2   1.50      1.500
9       2     3   1.60      1.760
10      2     4   1.93      2.123
11      2     5   1.95      2.145
```

This uses your rows' values as input to the function and applies it to each row. It grows new index at a rate of `index` + 10% if `time >= 2`.

Comment: I don't think your new_index column matches what the OP wanted.

Comment: @d_kennetz Yea I want the new_index to increase based on the previous observation of itself, so it grows independently from "index" after time 3